# Hot to single out numeric values from NMaximize

Tags: assignment, maximum

I have some problem with NMaximize.

The function NMaximize gives result like this

```
NMaximize[f[x],x]
{f[xmax] ,{x -> xmax}}
```

I've read in various answers that I can isolate xmax by writing:

```
NMaximize[f[x],x][[2]]
```

And I can get rid of the arrow, in order to obtain the numeric value of xmax, using /.

```
y /. NMaximize[f[x],x][[2]]
```

But then, when I type y, Mathematica doesn't give me back the numeric value of xmax, it just returns y again... What's wrong?

Comment: Did you try `x /. NMaximize[f[x],x][[2]]`?

Comment: Nope, but I don't want to assign to x any value, I need x to be a variable

Comment: Use @MichaelE2 to insure I'm pinged about your response.  -- I didn't assign any value to `x`; it's still a variable.  Do you want something like `x1 = x /. NMaximize[f[x],x][[2]]`?  Then the value is assigned to a symbol, namely `x1`, not `x`.  (Did you actually try my previous suggestion? Please do.)

Comment: Oooh, now I get it. Thank you, it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First example from the docs for [`NMaximize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMaximize.html):

> Find the global maximum of an unconstrained problem:
>
> ```
> NMaximize[-x^4 - 3 x^2 + x, x]
>
> {0.0825888, {x -> 0.16374}}
> ```
>
> Extract the maximizing argument:
>
> ```
> x /. Last[NMaximize[-x^4 - 3 x^2 + x, x]]
>
> 0.16374
> ```

Note that `ReplaceAll` (`/.`) replaces the symbol `x` with the number `0.16374`.
It does not assign a value to `x`.  If you want to store the value in another variable, use something like this:

```
x1 = x /. Last[NMaximize[-x^4 - 3 x^2 + x, x]]
```

Comment: There are also `NArgMax`  and `NMaxValue`

Answer (score 0):

you can write `y=f[x] /. NMaximize[f[x],x][[2]]`
or use `y=FindMaximum[f[x], x][[1]]`